# How to change the key of one map corresponding to a value in another map?

Tags: java, dictionary

I am working on a project in which I will be having a Map of String and Object coming to my below method. And suppose if this `data Map` contains like this -

```
a = p
b = q
c = r
d = s
e = t
f = u
g = v
h = w
i = x
```

where `a, b, c, d, e, f, g` is the key and `p, q, r, s, t, u, v` are there corresponding values in the above map.

Below is my method -

```
private void dataCheck(Map<String, Object> data) {


}
```

Now I have another static mapping like this in an another map which is of String and String -

```
public static final Map<String, String> STATIC_MAPPING = Collections.unmodifiableMap(new LinkedHashMap<String, String>() {{ 
put("a","hello");
put("b","world");
put("c","titan");
put("d","david");
put("e","elephant");
put("f","fire");
put("g","gel");
}});
```

here value of key `a` is `hello`, value of key `b` is `world`, value of key `c` is `titan` and same thing with other key value pairs.

Now in the below method as I have mentioned above, I will be getting values in the Map which will contain the data as shown above -

```
private void dataCheck(Map<String, Object> data) {

// how to get extract the value of the key from the 
//  STATIC_MAPPING map corresponding to data map key.


// print out a new map here with latest mappings

}
```

Now as data map will have `a = p`, it will get replace with `hello = p` because `a` is mapped to `hello` as shown in the STATIC_MAPPING and same with other fields as well. How can I do this efficiently?

And suppose if we don't have any mapping for the key in data map, then we will keep that as it is.

**UPDATE:-**

So my new map should have data like this -

```
hello = p
world = q
titan = r
david = s
elephant = t
fire = u
gel = v
h = w
i = x
```

As there was no mapping for key `h` and `i` so I will keep that as it is..

Comment: efficiently? What is wrong with the straightforward solution? Check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html to see what methods you have at your disposal to iterate over all the pairs in a map.

Comment: So, you want to create a new map containing the pairs of STATIC_MAPPING, but only if their key is also a key of data? Is that right?

Comment: @JBNizet: Yes, I guess comparing the key in the data map with key in the STATIC_MAPPING map and if it has any value, use that value as the key in the new map and the value of the original key in the data map.

Comment: I don't understand. Give  a concrete example of what you want as output given the example inputs you already gave.

Comment: @JBNizet: I just updated the question again. Now it should make sense.. Let me know if it is still unclear..

Comment: @SSH: just updated my answer according to your edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : data.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Object value = entry.getValue();
        String staticMappingValue = (String) STATIC_MAPPING.get(key);

        if (staticMappingValue != null) {
            newMap.put(staticMappingValue, value);
        } else {
            newMap.put(key, value);
        }
    }
```

So that `newMap`:

```
["hello":"p", "world":"q", etc..., "h":"w"]
```

**EDITED**: Followed Antoine Wils suggestion and reduced accesses to maps, since question highlighted efficiency.

Comment: @Antoine Wils: If you believe this answer is too inefficient, then either leave a comment on what you would change about it, or present your own answer. You have the necessary rep to do either one.

Comment: @John Y: indeed I can present my own answer. I didn't because I don't see the point of proposing a similar answer when its just about fine tuning a good answer. Isn't the point of editing to contribute to the community?

Comment: @AntoineWils: But your edit wasn't "fine tuning" from an editorial standpoint. It was a significant change. If you were correcting a missing semicolon or brace, or perhaps adjusting an obviously unintentional indentation error, then that would be fine. But you got rid of a lot of text and put in a lot of new text. Even if, from a computer science standpoint, it wasn't a big change, it's clearly not the code that the author came up with. If you feel strongly that you shouldn't contribute another answer, then comment instead and try to get the author to see things your way.

Comment: @jalopaba your answer fits the OP's question but it could be more efficient if you reduce the amount of accesses to the static map.

Comment: @AntoineWils Edited following your suggestion. Thanks.